# How to prevent code/option injection in a bash script

Tags: bash, code-injection

I have written a small bash script called "isinFile.sh" for checking if the first term given to the script can be found in the file "file.txt":

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE="file.txt"

if [ `grep -w "$1" $FILE` ]; then 
 echo "true"
else
 echo "false"
fi
```

However, running the script like

```
> ./isinFile.sh -x
```

breaks the script, since `-x` is interpreted by `grep` as an option. 
So I improved my script

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE="file.txt"

if [ `grep -w -- "$1" $FILE` ]; then 
 echo "true"
else
 echo "false"
fi
```

using `--` as an argument to grep. Now running

```
> ./isinFile.sh -x
false
```

works. But is using `--` the correct and only way to prevent code/option injection in bash scripts? I have not seen it in the wild, only found it mentioned in [ABASH: Finding Bugs in Bash Scripts](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~stevez/papers/MZ07.pdf).

Comment: Why are you using backquotes in `[` instead of just using `grep -q` directly?

Comment: I tried what you suggested, but
`if [ grep -q -w -- "$1" $ACCOUNTS_DGRID ]; ` doesn't work for me. I get errors like `./isinFile.sh: line 5: [: too many arguments`

Comment: He means without the square brackets, too: `if grep -q -w -- "$1" $ACCOUNTS_DGRID`

Comment: Ok, I see. So the answer to the comment of Ignacio is, that I didn't know about the `-q` option of `grep`. Thank you for that hint! But what is the advantage here of using `grep -q` compared to my version? I still have to use `--` to prevent option injection.

Comment: If you want `$1` to be treated as the regex, tell `grep` it is the regex: `grep -w -e "$1" "$FILE"`.  And you can check whether the `grep` worked with `-q`: `if grep -q -w -e "$1" "$FILE"; then echo "true"; else echo "false"; fi`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
grep -w -- ...
```

prevents that interpretation in what follows --

*EDIT*

(I did not read the last part sorry). Yes, it is the only way. The other way is to avoid it as first part of the search; e.g. `".{0}-x"` works too but it is odd., so e.g.

```
grep -w ".{0}$1" ...
```

should work too.

Comment: __important note__ the {} works with extended regex, so add the -E option; (sorry, I've aliased grep to grep -E so didn't noticed at the beginning)

Comment: You can do this in a basic regex (at least in the implementation of grep I tested with) by escaping the braces: `grep -w ".\{0\}$1" ...`

Comment: to ShinTakezou: Do you have another reference where the `--`-option is described? Or do you know the technical term for describing what `--` does, so one can search for it?

Comment: normally is a common practice on *nix/*nix-like systems, and I think it is common since is the way to tell getopt() to stop parsing for options (getopt() is a posix func that can be used to parse arguments): conventional, as usual: see http://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt and search for the sentence «The special argument "--" forces an end of option-scanning regardless of the scanning mode.»

Comment: @Gordon Davisson : thanks! but I find excaping of {} () + etc. ugly and prefer -E and consider them special and to have to escape if I do want them not special

Answer (score 3):

There's actually another code injection (or whatever you want to call it) bug in this script: it simply hands the output of `grep` to the `[` (aka `test`) command, and assumes that'll return true if it's not empty.  But if the output is more than one "word" long, `[` will treat it as an expression and try to evaluate it.  For example, suppose the file contains the line `0 -eq 2` and you search for "0" -- `[` will decide that 0 is not equal to 2, and the script will print false despite the fact that it found a match.

The best way to fix this is to use Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams' suggestion (as clarified by Dennis Williamson) -- this completely avoids the parsing problem, and is also faster (since `-q` makes `grep` stop searching at the first match).  If that option weren't available, another method would be to protect the output with double-quotes: `if [ "$(grep -w -- "$1" "$FILE")" ]; then` (note that I also used $() instead of backquotes 'cause I find them much easier to read, and quotes around $FILE just in case it contains anything funny, like whitespace).

Answer (score 1):

Though not applicable in this particular case, another technique can be used to prevent filenames that start with hyphens from being interpreted as options:

```
rm ./-x
```

or

```
rm /path/to/-x
```

Comment: To apply this fix programmatically, use something like: `[ "${FILE:0:1} = - ] && FILE="./$FILE"` (i.e. if FILE starts with a dash, add ./ in front of it).

Comment: @Gordon: Bash: `[[ $FILE == -* ]] ...`